# FeathersJS create compound index for collection

Tags: mongodb, feathersjs, compound-index

Is there any way with FeathersJS service to create a compound index for a MongoDB DB?

Comment: Are you using [`feathers-mongodb`](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-mongodb) or [`feathers-mongoose`](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-mongoose)? They would have different ways of approaching it. AFAIK the plain `feathers-mongodb` simply allows you to return the `Collection` object from the registered service. So you would just do that and then call [`createIndex()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#createIndex) just as you would with the regular node driver.

Comment: I'm using feathers-mongodb. Where should this "createIndex()" be done?

Comment: So it should basically be something like `service('service-name').Model.createIndex({ ... })` with all the regular `createIndex()` options for your compound index. The adapter is [nothing special](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-mongodb/blob/master/lib/index.js) and the `Model` property is simply a `Collection` object as already mentioned.

Comment: Hello Neil, sorry for bothering you again, but in my last question I meant where in the FeathersJS file structure should this be done? I've tried in "servicename.service.js" file, after the service sets the Model field of service variable, but it seems not to be working for me. Do you know exactly where in the FeathersJS file structure should it be done? Thanks!

Comment: Hello again... I was not defining correctly the compound index, now it is working, but I'm still wondering whether the place I've called the "createIndex()" is "FeathersJS compliant" or it should be done anywhere else not to break the FeathersJS intended flow...

Comment: Hi @JordiBlanch can you share what worked for you here?

Comment: Hello Chukwuma, in my case I finally didn't need a compound index and finally used a single unique index, but the procedure should be the same. Just go to the 'myservice.service.js' file and add a new line after 'service.Model = db.collection('myservice'); Use the function createIndex of the service.Model object (the DB), something like: 'service.Model.createIndex({ myField: 1 }, {unique: true});'. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Find the place where you create MongoDB client. If you used FeatherJS generator, - it is probably at `src/mongodb.js`. In the promise result where client is already available, - get the collection and add indexes:

```
// src/app.ts
import mongodb from './mongodb';
...
app.configure(mongodb);
...



// src/mongodb.ts
export default function (app: Application): void {
  const connection = app.get(`mongodb`);
  const database = connection.substr(connection.lastIndexOf(`/`) + 1);
  const mongoClient:Promise<Db> = MongoClient.connect(connection, {
    useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true
  }).then((client:MongoClient) => {
    const db:Db = client.db(database);
    try {
      db.collection(`users`).createIndex({ name: 1 });
    } catch(error:any) {
      console.error(`mongodb: failed to created indexes, error: `, error);
    }
    return db;
  });

  app.set(`mongoClient`, mongoClient);
}
```